# c# I need to find ingame ip + port

Tags: c#, command-line, wmic

How to get ip + port of a game running on my pc just by pressing on a execute bottom using CSharp ?

`Win32_Process WHERE Caption = 'mygame.exe'` i got this example

can someone tell me what code should i implement to get it ?
i know a command line to run in command line is

```
wmic process where name="my game" get commandline
```

but this will give me lots of info i just want result[0]= ip,result[1]=port

```
if (result.Count >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("IP: " + result[0]);
                Console.WriteLine("Port: " + result[1]);
            }
```